# Getting IP address of other NXT / Ardor peer nodes for Open API access?

Tags: nxt, ardor, nxt-api

I know that peer explorer has an API to access all the IP addresses of NXT / Ardor nodes via: http://www.peerexplorer.com/peerexplorer-api

But say peer explorer is down. How would one get the IP addresses of other NXT / Ardor nodes via a locally installed NXT / Ardor node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getPeers API and specify the desired service(s).  For example, to retrieve nodes with an open API (either HTTP or HTTPS) from an application, issue the following HTTP request:

```
https://localhost:7876/nxt?requestType=getPeers&service=API&service=API_SSL
```

You can use the API test page at http://localhost:7876/test from your browser to view the same information.